# IE10 Flexbox P element non-wrapping

Tags: internet-explorer, flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/pvJRK/2/

Basically in IE10 a p element which has text wider than it's parent when the "direction" is a row, will overflow, and subsequently push any other siblings out of the container. The wrapping appears to work fine in column mode (and you can view the same jsfiddle in Chrome and see it behave as expected).

```
<div id="flex-one">
    <p>Some extra long content (for the container) that correctly wraps!</p>
    <aside>Content</aside>
</div>

<div id="flex-two">
    <p>Some extra long content (for the container) that incorrectly wraps!</p>
    <aside>Content</aside>
</div>

div {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: blue;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#flex-one {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}

#flex-two {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

aside {
    background: red;
}
```

Any ideas on how to correct this behavior so that it doesn't overflow it's container? (without supplying a fixed with as this is used in a fluid layout).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to me, but adding `-ms-flex: 0 1 auto` or `-ms-flex: 1 1 auto` to the paragraph and aside corrects it in IE10.  By default, elements are supposed to have `flex: 0 1 auto` applied to them when they become flex items.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvJRK/3/

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I was running into this issue, but it was with all block level typographic elements - paragraphs and headers. It was driving me crazy!

Comment: I wanted to point out that the reason for this is because IE10 and 11 have a different default for flex items. This is simply because IE is useless.

Comment: As you can read [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), the default value for IE10 is `flex: 0 0 auto;`.

Comment: Alternatively, flex-shrink: 1 would be sufficient

Comment: 'IE 10 uses a different initial flex-shrink value' https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed

Answer (score 30):

For me, I needed to do this before it would start working for me:

(using classes for clarity and not including prefixes for brevity)

HTML:

```
<a class="flex">
    <span class="flex-child">Text that isn't wrapping in IE10</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Notice that you need to set naturally inline child elements to something other than inline (mainly `display:block` or `display:inline-block`) for the fix to work.

Thanks previous answers for getting me most of the way there though :)

**Update:**

The above technique does not work if flex-direction is set to column.

My recommendation for when flex-direction is set to column is to use a min-width media query to assign a max-width on desktop.

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

//a media query targeting desktop sort of sized screens
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .flex-child {
        display: block;
        max-width: 500px;//maximimum width of the element on a desktop sized screen
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This technique did the trick for me. By setting `display: block` and `max-width: 100%` on the child element it stopped the text from being displayed in a single line. Thank you for posting +1.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

My problem (http://jsfiddle.net/Hoffmeyer/xmjs1rmq/) was solved as described in flexbugs https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#2-column-flex-items-set-to-align-itemscenter-overflow-their-container

Set

```
max-width: 100%
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `flex-shrink: 1` to the parent of the elements which need wrapping has fixed this for me in IE10.

Note: `flex: 1 1 auto` (or `-ms-flex`) is a shorthand for:

```
flex-grow: 1
flex-shrink: 1
flex-basis: auto
```

In this case, it is specifically `flex-shrink` that will fix the issue. This property should be `1` by default, so I assume this is a bug with the IE10 implementation of flex box and by explicitly setting its value, it fixes the bug.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

this picture show the defult flex mean in IE 10, flex-shrink default in IE10 is 0;
so if the code is:

```
.title {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

<div class="title">
    <span class="title-name">some word word word</span>
    <label >some one checkbox</label>
</div>
```

but the span will not wrap in IE10, so the code need to be this:

```
.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.title-name{
    display: block;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```