# ie10 Flexbox text wrap issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="item">This is the text :D</span>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.parent{
    width: 150px;
}
.item{
    display: flex; /* other display: flex also declared eg. -ms-, -webkit- etc */
    align-items: center;
    &::before{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        margin-right: 1em;
        background: url('../linkToImg') no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

The above code will add an image in-front of the text and align the text to the middle of the image (Vertically).

**Codepen to see example**
http://codepen.io/aj372/pen/QKgXLA

On Chrome, Firefox and IE11, the text will wrap and won't overflow the parent container. However on IE10 specifically the text will not wrap at all. I have looked around on stackoverflow and additional places and none of the solutions works. This was one of the questions that asked a similar question.
[IE10 Flexbox P element non-wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808815/ie10-flexbox-p-element-non-wrapping). Another solution I tried was using `word-wrap` and `word-break`. Which all did not work. Is there a way to get the text to wrap on IE10?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37687667/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B unfortunately that does not work, the elements wrap but the text is still overflowing.